# Mocha hook for each test and test file

Tags: mocha.js

Is it possible to add a hook in mocha 8.1 for each test and test file?

Ex: I want to set a startup delay before each each in all the test files

Answer (score 0):

```
export const mochaHooks = {
  beforeEach(done) {
    // do something before every test
    done();
  }
};
```

https://mochajs.org/#available-root-hooks